# Is it possible to alias boost::make_iterator_range?

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, c++11

I am having trouble aliasing the function `boost::make_iterator_range`

(I would like to hide boost behind an alias in case this particular library gets adopted into the standard sometime in the future.)

Is there any way this can be made to work?

```
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>

void Foo()
{
}

template< typename T >
void Bar()
{ }

template< typename T >
void Bar(char c)
{ }

void (&FooAlias)() = Foo;           // ok
void (&BarAlias)() = Bar<int>;      // ok

// boost::iterator_range<const size_t*> (&MakeIterRangeAlias)(const size_t*,const size_t*) = 
//  boost::make_iterator_range<const size_t*>;  // not ok

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const size_t v[] = { 3, 5, 1, 5, 29, 15 };

    boost::iterator_range<const size_t*> r 
        = boost::make_iterator_range( std::begin( v ), std::end( v )); // want to alias this

    return 0;
}
```

The error message is:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/iterator/iterator_categories.hpp:15:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/iterator/detail/facade_iterator_category.hpp:7,
                 from /usr/include/boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/range/iterator_range_core.hpp:23,
                 from /usr/include/boost/range/iterator_range.hpp:13,
                 from sandbox.cpp:2:
/usr/include/boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp: In instantiation of ‘boost::mpl::eval_if_c<true, boost::range_const_iterator<const long unsigned int*>, boost::range_mutable_iterator<const long unsigned int* const> >’:
/usr/include/boost/range/iterator.hpp:63:63:   instantiated from ‘boost::range_iterator<const long unsigned int* const>’
sandbox.cpp:20:10:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp:60:31: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘boost::mpl::eval_if_c<true, boost::range_const_iterator<const long unsigned int*>, boost::range_mutable_iterator<const long unsigned int* const> >::f_ {aka struct boost::range_const_iterator<const long unsigned int*>}’
/usr/include/boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp: In instantiation of ‘boost::mpl::eval_if_c<false, boost::range_const_iterator<const long unsigned int*>, boost::range_mutable_iterator<const long unsigned int*> >’:
/usr/include/boost/range/iterator.hpp:63:63:   instantiated from ‘boost::range_iterator<const long unsigned int*>’
sandbox.cpp:20:10:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp:60:31: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘boost::mpl::eval_if_c<false, boost::range_const_iterator<const long unsigned int*>, boost::range_mutable_iterator<const long unsigned int*> >::f_ {aka struct boost::range_mutable_iterator<const long unsigned int*>}’
sandbox.cpp:20:10: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘void (&)(const size_t*, const size_t*) {aka void (&)(const long unsigned int*, const long unsigned int*)}’ from an rvalue of type ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’
make: *** [sandbox] Error 1
```

Comment: The first problem that I see is that the return type of the alias is wrong (it should be `boost::iterator_range<const size_t*>`, not `void`).

Comment: The 2nd argument to `make_iterator_range` should be `&v[n]`. It should point to element after the last one. And since you've tagged [c++11], use `std::begin` and [`std::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) to avoid having to calculate the `n`.

Comment: @Mankarse +1 good point: OP modified

Comment: @KennyTM +1 you're right: OP modified

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using function pointers is a suboptimal way alias a function.  It is not as flexible as the original (it can no longer be a template) and you now need to know the exact signature of the function, which may or may not be stable.
Instead try this approach.

```
template< typename ... Args >
auto MakeIterRangeAlias( Args&& ... args ) -> decltype( /* copy return line here */ )
{
   return boost::make_iterator_range( std::forward<Args>(args)... );
}
```

With almost no work on your part the alias supports the exact signature of the original.  Even if it dramatically changes, you're still set.  Further, unlike the function pointer approach the optimizer will be able to trivially inline MakeIterRangeAlias so that there is no runtime overhead.

Comment: @deft-code great suggestion, but I'm having trouble getting it to work.  Even after filling out decltype(), if I take out the T in the template parameter, it compiles, but then a call to MakeIterRangeAlias fails to bind properly.  I am using gcc 4.6.1

Comment: @kfmfe04: Sorry, that's what happens when you submit code without compiling it.  Here is a working proof of concept using `std::make_pair` instead, [ideone.com/XVTxa](http://ideone.com/XVTxa)

Comment: @deft-code - woohoo - works great now - thx for getting me into variadic templates, too